# Share printer with Win XP server and Win 7 client

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, printer, network-printer

I have a 32 bit Windows XP computer with a installed Epson R200 printer. I shared this printer and want to use it with a 64 bit Windows 7 system, now.

But the problem is, that the Windows 7 client didn't find a driver for that printer. If I plug the printer directly to the Windows 7 system it works without problems.

Any idea how I can share this printer correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When sharing printer for multiple systems that diffrentiate between themselfs you need to install **Additional drivers**. Here's a helpful [article](http://www.labnol.org/software/share-printer-between-different-windows-computers/9530/) that should get you started.

Basically you need to download from a website drivers for both 32/64bit and then install printer on your XP with 32bit drivers. Then in Printer properties under sharing Tab you find `additional drivers` list where you need to choose right drivers and install them properly.